# Fatal error for WooCommerce Rest API "PUT" request (update product)

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am trying to update the product via the WooCommerce REST API. But I am getting an error.

This is the HTML form:

```
<form action="update_product_connect.php" name="update" method="post">
<tbody>
<?php foreach ( $data as $row ) : ?>
<tr>
<td><?= $row['id']; ?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="namee" value="<?= $row['name']; ?>"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="descriptions" value="<?= $row['description']; ?>"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="short_descriptions" value="<?= $row['short_description']; ?>"/></td>
<td><input type="number" name="regular_pricee" value="<?= $row['regular_price']; ?>"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="sil" value="kaydet" /></form>
</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And this is the code inside the **update_product_connect.php** file that sends the HTTP call to update the product.

```
<?php
$dataname = $_POST['namee'];
$dataprice = $_POST['regular_pricee'];
$datadescription = $_POST['descriptions'];
$datashort_description = $_POST['short_descriptions'];
$data = 
[
'name'  => $_POST['namee'],
'regular_price'  => $_POST['regular_pricee'],
'description' => $_POST['descriptions'],
'short_description' => $_POST['short_descriptions'],

];
?>
<?php echo json_encode($woocommerce->PUT('products', $data)); ?>
```

Below is a screenshot of the error I'm getting:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it is because **you are not entering the product ID** to be updated in the `$woocommerce->PUT()` request endpoint.

I see that in the form you have neither the product SKU nor the product ID. You will need to add them to let WooCommerce know which product needs to be updated.

It should be something like this:

```
<?php
$product_id = 123;
echo json_encode($woocommerce->PUT("products/{$product_id}", $data));
?>
```

or:

```
<?php
$sku = 'B-678';
$product_id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $sku );
echo json_encode($woocommerce->PUT("products/{$product_id}", $data));
?>
```

You can find more information here:

- [WooCommerce Rest API Docs - Update a product](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#update-a-product)

**USEFUL ANSWERS**

- [REST API: No route was found matching the URL and request method](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/350009/rest-api-no-route-was-found-matching-the-url-and-request-method)
- [Error "No route was found matching the URL and request method" when call api](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/14629)

Comment: Thank you very much for your priority answer and support.
I can update as you specify without any problems.but,I do not know how to create a form and update a product I selected. I can do all operations such as adding a product, deleting a product, on the form. but i can't update the data on the form i created

Comment: Maybe you know. I am using the automattic rest api files and using these files I can create a form, add a product, add a product, add an order, delete an order. Finally, the product update remained

Comment: It could be very good if I could see a simple update form. I could not find it in any way on the internet

Comment: Did you create the HTML code of the form? The update of the product data can be done in several ways. Where will the form be?

Comment: I'm just trying to learn its logic right now. So even if I have this form in an empty html, it's enough for me.

Comment: https://imgur.com/ppM7ziF For example, my current form is such a plain page

Comment: `$row['id'];` is the product ID? If yes, you will need to convert `<td><?= $row['id']; ?></td>` with `<td><input type="text" name="id" value="' . $row["id"] . '" readonly/></td>`. This way you can get the product ID from the **update_product_connect.php** file like so: `$_POST['id'];`. Make sure that the **name** attribute values of each form field are unique on the page.

Comment: https://imgur.com/3seu0bc don't really understand why it gives such error in value. I got an error before when I gave an error with an href in value.

Comment: If it's an HTML page (and not PHP) try using this: `<td><input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" readonly/></td>`.

Comment: I solved this issue, thank you very much for your support.
Is it possible to support you for the issue here at a convenient time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67654572/i-cant-list-the-selected-product-of-woocommerce-rest-api @Vincenzo Di Gaetano